# Symmetries in the equations and graphs of complex-valued polynomials

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, symmetry, visualization

I tried to visualize the complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \dots + a_1z + a_0$$

following some obvious thoughts:

1. For **any** complex function $f(z) = 0$ just means $\operatorname{Re}f(z) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Im}f(z) = 0$.
2. $\operatorname{Re}f(z)$ and  $\operatorname{Im}f(z)$ can both be considered as functions $F(u,v)$,  $G(u,v)$ of two real variables (with $z = u + iv$), thus defining two two-dimensional surfaces "over" the plane  $\mathbb{R}^2$.
3. $F(u,v) = 0$ and $G(u,v) = 0$ define the intersections of these surfaces with the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, which for polynomials are two  different one-dimensional objects, i.e. unions of some curves and possibly isolated points ("generalized curves").
4. The roots of $f$, i.e. the numbers with $f(z) = 0$, are exactly the intersections of these intersections: the points (= numbers) with $\operatorname{Re}f(z) = F(u,v) = 0$ **and** $\operatorname{Im}f(z) = G(u,v) = 0.$

For polynomials the roots are isolated points: at least 1 and at most $n$ of them (for $n$ the degree of $f$). That's the essence of the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

For $f(z) = z^3 + a_2z^2 + a_1z + a_0$ and $a_0 = a_2 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1,2,3,4$ the curves $F(u,v)=0$ (red) and $G(u,v)=0$ (blue) look like this:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]
<sub>[interactive version](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ioxy1wsgcx)</sub>

Note, that the generalized curve $\operatorname{Re}f(z) = F(u,v) = 0$ (red) plays the role of the graph of $f(x)$ for real arguments, while the generalized curve $\operatorname{Im}f(z) = G(u,v) = 0$ (blue) plays the role of the real axis $y = 0$: the (real resp. complex) roots are their intersections. (Note, that the real axis $v=0$ is contained in $G(u,v) = 0$ for all polynomials.)

Determining $F(u,v)$ and $G(u,v)$ for degree $n=2,3,4$ yields

**n=2**: 
$f(z) = z^2 + a_1z +a_0$
$F(u,v) = a_1u + (u^2-v^2) + a_0$
$G(u,v) =  a_1v + (uv +uv)$
$ = v(a_1 + 2u)$

**n=3**:
$f(z) = z^3 + a_2z^2 + a_1z +c$
$F(u,v) = a_1u + a_2(u^2-v^2) + (u^3 -3uv^2) + a_0$
$G(u,v) =  a_1v + a_2(uv + vu) -(v^3 -3u^2v) $
$ = v(a_1 + 2a_2u - (v^2 - 3u^2))$

**n=4**:
$f(z) = z^4 + a_3z^3 + a_2z^2 + a_1z +c$
$F(u,v) = a_1u + a_2(u^2-v^2) + a_3(u^3 -3uv^2) +  (u^4 + v^4) + a_0$
$G(u,v) =  a_1v + a_2(uv + vu) -a_3(v^3 -3u^2v) + 4(u^3v - uv^3) $
$ = v(a_1 + 2a_2u - a_3(v^2 - 3u^2) + 4(u^3 - uv^2))$

which shows some "formulaic symmetry" between  $F(u,v)$ and $G(u,v)$. It also reveals that

- $G(u,0) = 0$
- $F(u,v) = F(u,-v)$
- $G(u,v) = G(u,-v)$

which is the reason that complex roots always come in conjugate pairs.

My questions are:

> What are the general formulas for $F(u,v)$ and $G(u,v)$ for arbitrary degree $n$? (I didn't manage to write it down.)
>
> Does possibly this relation between $F(u,v)$ and $G(u,v)$ lie at the
>   heart of the fundamental theorem of algebra: Because $F(u,v)$ and
>   $G(u,v)$ are related like this, each polynomial has 1 to $n$ roots?
>
> How are these symmetries related to the symmetries between the roots of $f(z)$ investigated in Galois theory and to the fact that the coefficients $a_i$ are symmetric functions of the roots $z_i$?

---

For the sake of comparison this is how $F(u,v) = 0$ and $G(u,v)=0$ look like for $f(z) = (z-a)(z-b)(z-c)$ with $a = 1, c = 2$ and $b = 1,2,3,4$

[image] [image]

[image] [image]
<sub>[interactive version](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sny2pfka1k)</sub>

Comment: A random comment: the fundamental theorem of algebra also deals with polynomials with complex coefficients, which do not have the symmetries $G(u, v) = G(u, -v)$ and so on.

Comment: Ok then, but there's a restricted version for real coefficients which might be proved independently.

Comment: @HansStricker, the FTA for real polynomials is equivalent to the FTA for complex polynomials because $g\bar g$ is a real polynomial with the same zeros as $g$.

Comment: Does this make Joppy's comment obsolete?